# Roots to an equation using analysis

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $a_{1}<a_{2}<…<a_{n}$. Prove that the equation

$ \frac{1}{x-a_{1}}+\frac{1}{x-a_{2}} +…+\frac{1}{x-a_{n}}=c$ has exactly $n-1$ roots if $c=0$ and $n$ roots if $c\neq 0$.

---

I am absolutely not sure but I think I need to use Rolle's theorem on this. Multiply both sides by $x-a_{1}$ so we get:

$1+\frac{x-a_{1}}{x-a_{2}}+…+\frac{x-a_{1}}{x-a_{n}}-c(x-a_{1})=0$. Now it is defined for $a_{1}$ but not for $a_{2},…,a_{n}.$. If we consider the interval $(a_{1}-\varepsilon,a_{n}+\varepsilon), \varepsilon>0$ we get..nowhere. I want to create an interval with endpoints that are solutions to the equation. Yet I don't know how to prove that there are exactly $n$ roots(Fundamental theorem of algebra can't be used).

Comment: Yes you can use the fundamental theorem of algebra. Clearing out denominators, you obtain a polynomial equation in degree $n$.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x-a_k}-c$. Then $f'(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(x-a_k)^2}$,
so $f$ is decreasing on each interval 
$I_0=(-\infty,a_1),I_1=(a_1,a_2),I_2=(a_2,a_3), \ldots, I_{n-1}=(a_{n-1},a_n),
I_n=(a_n,+\infty)$.

Also, note that ${\lim}_{x \to a_k,x < a_k}f(x)=-\infty$ and
${\lim}_{x \to a_k,x > a_k}f(x)=+\infty$ and
${\lim}_{x \to -\infty}f(x)={\lim}_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-c$.

This shows that $f(x)=0$ has exactly one root in each $I_k$ for $1\leq k <n$.

If $c>0$, then $f$ has no root in $I_0$ and exactly one root in $I_n$.

If $c<0$, then $f$ has no root in $I_n$ and exactly one root in $I_0$.

If $c=0$, $f$ has no root in $I_0$ or $I_n$.

Comment: That's nice Ewan, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

It is an equation I work around for almost 50 years. I published a paper in 2010 (Chemical Engineering Research and Design, 88 (2010) pp.602-605). I still work the problem of the definition of a tighter window containing the solution between two asymptotes. I should be delighted to share with you any idea or track we could follow together.

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy. As I posted it, I am very concerned (for decades) by finding upper and lower bounds of the solution between two asymptotes. Do you have any idea ? Thanks in advance